# How Do I Fix Nginx Site Redirecting Too Many Times On Vue App

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

This is a vue application running on nginx ubuntu 18.04. Here is the code snippet from the nginx config for the site. I noticed that when visiting the site, I would get a message stating "too many redirects". This will only happen when visiting the non https version of this site.

Im on a custom droplet on digital ocean if that helps.

Im not sure where to go from here. If you need any more information, I can provide.

Thanks for everyone's time.

```
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;
    index index.html;
    server_name www.digyt.co  digyt.co;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/digyt_co/digyt_co.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.digyt.co;
    return 301 $scheme://digyt.co$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: Try: `return 301 https://digyt.co$request_uri permanent;`